# How to add True USD on Myrtherwallet

Tags: myetherwallet, trueusd

i want to buy some true USD tokens, how should i add it on myetherwallet?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the url below:-
https://medium.com/@giacomo.licari/using-smart-contracts-abi-myetherwallet-9ad20aaa9900